# Volatile variable visibility guarantees in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have checked out some posts about volatile variables in java but I am still a bit confused, not to mention some of them contradict each other. Here is an example I would like to ask about:

```java
public class Main {


     static  ArrayList<Integer> list= new ArrayList<>();
     static volatile int listSize=0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread writer = new Thread(Main::write);
        Thread reader = new Thread(Main::read);
        writer.start();
        reader.start();
    }
    public static void write(){
        while (true){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return;
            }
            list.add(1);
            listSize++;
            System.out.println("Added an element.");

        }
    }
    public static void read(){
        int currentIndex=0;
        while (true){
            if(currentIndex>=listSize){
                continue;
            }
            System.out.println("Read an element.");
            int element = list.get(currentIndex);
            currentIndex++;
            //do stuff with element...
        }
    }
}
```

So in this example a writer thread writes to an ArrayList and a reader thread reads the elements from that list. According to some answers on this topic even if I made the list itself volatile it  would have no visibility guarantees between threads for the contents of the list, only for the list object itself. In other words if the writer thread would do this:

```java
list = new ArrayList<>();
```

The reader thread would know about it. But if the writer thread is adding/removing/modifying the list, like in the example above, there are no guarantees the reader thread would ever see it. And here is a quote from a book called "Java Concurrency in Practice"

> The visibility effects of volatile variables extend beyond the value of the volatile variable itself. When thread A writes to a volatile variable and subsequently thread B reads that same variable, the values of all variables that were visible to A prior to writing to the volatile variable become visible to B after reading the volatile variable. So from a memory visibility perspective, writing a volatile variable is like exiting a synchronized block and reading a volatile variable is like entering a synchronized block.

This quote is also the reason I made a volatile int that the writer thread increments whenever it writes to the list instead of making the list itself volatile. So I tested this example with and without the volatile variable (replacing *currentIndex>=listSize* with *currentIndex>=list.size()* ), and without the volatile variable the reader thread blocks completely, never actually seeing the added elements to the list. With the volatile variable though the reader thread instantly sees the change to the list. Seemingly the quote from the book is correct but I would like to be sure since the example I wrote is based on something else I am writing, and it wouldn't be great if the reader thread blocks indefinitely.

Edit: The thread spin is to get a better chance at caching.

Comment: Reading a value from a volatile variable that was written by another thread creates a happened-before relationship. The quote is correct. Note the conditionality of it though: If a threads reads a value x from a volatile variable, that thread is guaranteed to see the writes that a writing thread did before it wrote the value x.

Comment: Note that busy-waiting is not really a good thing. If you need to use busy-wait with a volatile, that is not a good use case for volatile.

Comment: @BurakSerdar I busy waited in the example to get a better chance at caching. I know busy waiting is bad.

Answer (score 3):

The very next sentence of "Java Concurrency in Practice" (after the part you cited) is:

> However, we do not recommend relying too heavily on volatile variables for visibility; code that relies on volatile variables for visibility of arbitrary state is more fragile and harder to understand than code that uses locking.

In that sense, I recommend to use a full featured synchronization mechanism (either `synchronized` or via advanced locks) to ensure thread safety instead of relying on sideeffects of `volatile`.

Apart from that, your code has a busy-wait loop - you should definitely avoid that! (Maybe that's just for the example code)

This is a valid example of your code that uses proper synchronization with conditional wait (instead of a busy-wait loop):

```
public class Main {
    static  ArrayList<Integer> list= new ArrayList<>();
    static volatile int listSize=0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread writer = new Thread(Main::write);
        Thread reader = new Thread(Main::read);
        writer.start();
        reader.start();
    }

    public static void write(){
        while (true){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return;
            }

            // all access to shared state should be synchronized
            synchronized(this) {
                list.add(1);
                listSize++;
                notifyAll(); // notifiy waiting reader thread(s)
            }
            System.out.println("Added an element.");
        }
    }

    public static void read(){
        int currentIndex=0;
        while (true) {
            int element = 0;

            // all access to shared state should be synchronized
            synchronized(this) {
                while (currentIndex >= listSize) {
                    wait(); // wait for notifications of writer thread(s)
                }

                System.out.println("Read an element.");
                element = list.get(currentIndex);
            }
            currentIndex++;
            // do stuff with element...
        }
    }
}
```

(Note that in read-world code you would rather use any of the existing concurrent collection classes instead, e.g. `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue`)

Comment: Visibility guarantees of volatile variables are not "side effects"

Comment: Well maybe I should. It's just that in my case It doesn't really matter if one thread reads and another writes to the ArrayList at the same time. I just have to make sure the reader thread actually sees that someone has written something to the list at some point (that point doesn't even have to be right after the write happens). So I feel like synchronizing reads and writes would unnecessarily make things slower.

Comment: @iexav If you keep the busy-wait loop, you'll have much bigger problems than a code that is slower for some nanoseconds: A CPU core at 100% workload.

Comment: @iexav Usually, a clean, understandable code weighs far more than a performance impact that you might probably not notice at all. If you are unsure, measure both versions, but make sure that in your non-obviously synchronized version you do not do busy-waiting, as this will destroy everything.

Comment: @BurakSerdar for 99.9% of all Java developer, these are side-effects that (imho) should not be used for some kind of optimizations. Reason: Usually, the impact is minimal compared to other things that could be done to improve performance (if necessary at all). So usually clean code goes over performance tweaks. Of course, there are always a few cases where such optimizations make sense, but imho its the last thing one should do.

Comment: I agree that for this case, volatile should not be used. There are other cases where they make perfect sense, like a thread-safe counter.

Comment: @BurakSerdar sure, for very specialized concurrency utils, written by very specialized concurrency experts, it's perfectly fine. ;-)

Comment: @isnot2bad I suppose I can try it out. It's probably gonna take a while to refactor the code though. Also why would busy-waiting destroy everything?

Comment: @iexav a busy-wait loop (or spin-wait loop) keeps the executing thread busy all the time, as it has to loop without any chance to pause. So it will cause your CPU to work heavily and probably loop several billion times until `listSize` changes after 10 seconds, just to enter the loop again... (see also page 295 of the book)
So your CPU is prevented from doing other stuff in these 10 seconds, so other threads might not get the chance to be executed. This is called "starvation".

Comment: @isnot2bad My bad*. I am not busy waiting in the original code. I sleep the thread. Here I busy-waited to get a better chance at caching.

Comment: @iexav that's what I thought at first. But sleeping is not a good option either (although far better than busy-waiting), as the thread (1) might "oversleep" the change (resulting in poor responsiveness), or (2) might have a huge scheduling overhead, if the sleeping time is very short (so it awakes very often).

Comment: @isnot2bad The sleeping I have in my original code is temporary. Even if it wasn't though and I just left it there for good in my particular case that would not be a problem at all. I can sleep it for like a second and it still wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @isnot2bad But yes. I am more than well aware of the scheduling overhead and poor responsiveness as once upon a time I tried to synchronize thread sleeps with the refresh time of my monitor. Fun times.

Answer (score 0):

The quote from "Java Concurrency in Practice" is correct. We can verify this by consulting the [Java Language Specification, section 17.4.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4):

> - An unlock action on monitor m synchronizes-with all subsequent lock actions on m (where "subsequent" is defined according to the synchronization order).
> - A write to a volatile variable v (§8.3.1.4) synchronizes-with all subsequent reads of v by any thread (where "subsequent" is defined according to the synchronization order).

That is, there is no semantic difference between unlocking a monitor and then locking it in another thread, and writing a volatile variable and then reading it in another thread. Both cause the threads involved to synchronize.

And synchronizing does indeed make all earlier changes visible to the other thread, not just the changes to the variable or monitor used to effect the synchronization. This is specified in [section 17.4.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5):

> Two actions can be ordered by a happens-before relationship. If one action happens-before another, then the first is visible to and ordered before the second.
>
> If we have two actions `x` and `y`, we write `hb(x, y)` to indicate that `x` happens-before `y`.
>
> - If `x` and `y` are actions of the same thread and `x` comes before `y` in program order, then `hb(x, y)`.
> - ...
> - If an action `x` synchronizes-with a following action `y`, then we also have `hb(x, y)`.
> - If `hb(x, y)` and `hb(y, z)`, then `hb(x, z)`.

Let's apply this to your code, where the writer thread does:

```
        list.add(1);  // action A
        listSize++;   // action B
```

and the reader thread does:

```
        currentIndex >= listSize; // action C
        list.get(currentIndex);   // action D
```

Then, we have

- `hb(A, B)` because `A` and `B` are in the same thread, and `A` comes before `B` in program order
- `hb(B, C)` because `B` synchronizes-with `C`, because `B` is a write to a volatile variable, and `C` a read of that variable, which we know to be subsequent in synchronization order, because we would have repeated if it had read the old value
- `hb(C, D)` because `C` and `D` are in the same thread, and `C` comes before `D` in program order

therefore, we have both `hb(A,B)` and `hb(B,C)`, and therefore `hb(A,C)`, and as we also have `h(C,D)`, we have `h(A,D)`.

Therefore, `A` is visible to `D`.

That is, if the reader thread sees a new list size, the reader thread is guaranteed to see the list contents as well, in spite of these not being declared volatile.

However, your code is nevertheless unsafe. Suppose the writer thread continues its loop and does:

```
list.add(1); // action E
```

Then, we have neither `hb(D, E)` nor `hb(E, D)`. Two threads, one writer and one reader, are accessing the same list at the same time. That's a data race, and the Java Language guarantees sequential consistency only for programs free of data races.

Allow me to end this post with some advice about writing safe multithreaded code:

- For most everyday concurrency needs, the `java.util.concurrent` package contains a ready made implementation written by an expert. For instance, to write elements in a thread, and read them in another, you could simply use a `BlockingQueue`. Then, you wouldn't have to deal with any concurrency primitives yourself.
- The famous quote "premature optimization is the root of all evil" is always worth keeping in mind, but especially where writing corect code is hard, such as when doing concurrency by yourself. Don't worry about the cost of a synchronized block (unless you have measurements that prove it to be a problem), worry about getting your code correct and reliable.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation and the recommendations  :)

Answer (score 0):

> So in this example a writer thread writes to an ArrayList and a reader thread reads the elements from that list.

Only when you are sharing *fields* between threads can `volatile` be used and only in certain situations.  In your case, if you are sharing an `ArrayList` then the fields inside of the object are not protected.  Either you should be a using a `BlockingQueue` which is internally synchronized or you should use the `synchronized` keyword around both the write and read operations in your two threads.

```
// writer thread
synchronized (list) {
   list.add(x);
}
...
// writer thread
synchronized (list) {
   if (currentIndex < list.size() {
     int element = list.get(currentIndex);
     ...
   }
}
```

> The reader thread would know about it. But if the writer thread is adding/removing/modifying the list, like in the example above, there are no guarantees

Yes but there are two things going on here that you need to worry about.  There is memory synchronization and mutex locking.  When you are making multiple operations on a shared field or shared object then simply making it `volatile` won't work.  Even the ++ is multiple operations: get-increment-store.  Any shared objects, like your `ArrayList` will need to be fully `synchronized` to be shared during read/write operations.

> without the volatile variable the reader thread blocks completely, never actually seeing the added elements to the list

Right.  Without any memory barriers to force updates to cached memory, there may be no change in the reader thread CPU cache.  Modern processors actually update the cache through hardware but that depends on your processor type and it doesn't get around the race conditions.

> With the volatile variable though the reader thread instantly sees the change to the list.

Using a `volatile` in this manner is not recommended since it is relying on the side effects of the volatile variable access.  For example, someone later could move the `listSize++;` to be before the `list.add(...)` which in looking at the code block would be fine but would break the visibility of the `list` changes.

Comment: I suppose the contradictions still remain. At the very least there is one point of equilibrium: I should use a synchronized list.

Comment: Could I trouble you to provide some evidence for the claims in your last paragraph? The Java Language Specification seems to disagree to with you ... (as my answer shows).

Comment: Yeah I was incorrect.  I thought that the publishing of all other variables was implementation specific and although commonplace was not guaranteed by the memory model specifically.  I've removed that paragraph.  Thanks @meriton.